# How can I refactor this Python code to make it more readable and compact?

Tags: python-3.x, refactoring, adventure

I wrote a function to handle selecting and using items to regain the player's health in a text adventure. What would be the best way to shrink the following code? Any feedback or constructive criticism would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Also, I'm really struggling to understand Object Oriented Programming. Does anyone have a recommendation for a book on the subject of OOP (preferably taught with Python examples)?

```py
def use_item(action):
    print("What item do you want to use? Type the name of the item.")
    print("Inventory:")
    for items in player_inventory:
        print(items)
        action = input("> ")
        if action == "fruit":
            if action == "fruit" and "Fruit" not in player_inventory:
                print("You don't have any fruit.")
                print("Enter 'u' again if you want to select something else.")
            elif action == "fruit" and "Fruit" in player_inventory:
                print("You ate some fruit. You are refreshed.")
                player_inventory.remove("Fruit")
                player_health += 25
                if player_health > 100:
                    player_health = 100
                    print("You have",player_health,"health.")
                else:
                    print("Invalid choice! Try again.")
        elif action == "bread":
            if action == "bread" and "Bread" not in player_inventory:
                print("You don't have any bread.")
                print("Enter 'u' again if you want to select something else.")
            elif action == "bread" and "Bread" in player_inventory:
                print("You ate some bread. You are refreshed.")
                player_inventory.remove("Bread")
                player_health += 50
                if player_health > 100:
                    player_health = 100
                    print("You have",player_health,"health.")
                else:
                    print("Invalid choice! Try again.")
        elif action == "meat":
            if action == "meat" and "Meat" not in player_inventory:
                print("You don't have any meat.")
                print("Enter 'u' again if you want to select something else.")
            elif action == "meat" and "Meat" in player_inventory:
                print("You ate some meat. You are refreshed.")
                player_inventory.remove("Meat")
                player_health += 75
                if player_health > 100:
                    player_health = 100
                    print("You have",player_health,"health.")
                else:
                    print("Invalid choice! Try again.")
        elif action == "elixir":
            if action == "elixir" and "Elixir" not in player_inventory:
                print("You don't have any elixir.")
                print("Enter 'u' again if you want to select something else.")
            elif action == "elixir" and "elixir" in player_inventory:
                print("You ate drank an elixir. You are fully healed.")
                player_inventory.remove("Elixir")
                player_health += 100
                if player_health > 100:
                    player_health = 100
                    rint("You have",player_health,"health.")
                else:
                    print("Invalid choice! Try again.")
        else:
            print("Invalid choice! Try again.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that has just the if/elif/else logic and each logic to have it's own function. 
Really good explanation
https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/